# Understanding 'context' in GraphQL - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I am reading GraphQL mutation part, and I do not understand what is `context` in this part, and what `context[:current_user]` returns

This is the sample code:

```rb
class Mutations::PromoteEmployee < Mutations::BaseMutation
  def ready?(**args)
    # Called with mutation args.
    # Use keyword args such as employee_id: or **args to collect them
    if !context[:current_user].admin?
      raise GraphQL::ExecutionError, "Only admins can run this mutation"
    else
      # Return true to continue the mutation:
      true
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

This is guides link: https://graphql-ruby.org/mutations/mutation_authorization.html

Comment: I just want to know how context look like in this situation?

Answer (score 7):

You can provide application-specific values to GraphQL as context:. This is available in many places:

- resolve functions
- Schema#resolve_type hook
- ID generation & fetching

Common uses for context: include the current user or auth token. To provide a context: value, pass a hash to Schema#execute:

```
    # graphql_controller.rb

    context = {
      current_user: session[:current_user],
      current_organization: session[:current_organization],
    }

    MySchema.execute(query_string, context: context)
```

Then, you can access those values during execution:

```
    field :post, Post, null: true do
      argument :id, ID, required: true
    end

    def post(id:)
      context[:current_user] # => #<User id=123 ... >
      # ...
    end
```

Note that context is not the hash that you passed it. It's an instance of `{{ "GraphQL::Query::Context" | api_doc }}`, but it delegates `#[]`, `#[]=`, and a few other methods to the hash you provide.